# HDD on a S Type VM Azure

Tags: azure

When you resize a VM to a series that only supports SSD you get the following warning

> You've chosen to use a standard disk on a size that supports premium
>   disks. This could impact operating system performance and is not
>   recommended. Consider using premium storage (SSD) instead.

If the VM does not require SSD due to its usage is this really something to worry about?

We have a few VM that is set up with HDD and we are going to move them to the Azure B-Series VMs as a cost-saving exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the VM does not require SSD due to its usage is this really
>   something to worry about?

In Azure, SSD have a high performance. If your VM does not require SSD, we can select to use HDD.

As far as I know, **nothing** need to worry about, just need to consider IO.

Comment: Yep, helpful. The message you get within azure should be more inline with above. Basically we are making use of the burst size VMs and these only come in sizes that suggest SSD. We are moving some F sized VMs to B and we get this warning.

Comment: Tbh, we just did it and reviewed performance and we are very happy with the performance of the B VMs

Comment: @SteveDrake Thank you for your feedback, that message should add more information about it. I will add this to Azure feedback.